# how to read single observation contained in multiple line in python?

Tags: python

I have a data where single observation comes from multiple lines. in the below data, the first-line represents ID, first name & last name, the second line represents category & the third line explains the start weight and end weight.

```
1023 David Shaw
red
189 165
1049 Amelia Serrano
yellow
145 124
```

desired output:

| Obs | IdNumber | fname | lname | category | StartWeight | EndWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1023 | David | Shaw | red | 189 | 165 |
| 2 | 1049 | Amelia | Serrano | yellow | 145 | 124 |

Can anyone help me with how can I write a python code to read a single observation from multiple lines? I can do the same using SAS with line pointer (#). Below is the link for the same.

ref link: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/basess/p0s16wvzu0z9q7n0zmxia30s6qyc.htm

Comment: What issues are you having with reading the file in as a list, then getting three elements from a list (hint: use slices)?

Comment: How would this "single observation" be stored? The answer depends on this.

Comment: Show your desired output.

Comment: Hi, i want to create a python dataframe on which i can do multiple analysis. i am new to python and pandas default reading methods (read_csv, read_excel) are not effective here.

Comment: I have added desired output in the post. kindly suggest me how can I achieve above results using python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

def read():
    Id, FirstName, LastName = input().strip().split()
    category = input()
    sWeight, eWeight = map(int, input().split())
    data['Id'].append(int(Id))
    data['FirstName'].append(FirstName)
    data['LastName'].append(LastName)
    data['category'].append(category)
    data['sWeight'].append(sWeight)
    data['eWeight'].append(eWeight)

data = {"Id" : [], "FirstName" : [], "LastName" : [], "category" : [], "sWeight" : [], "eWeight" : []}

read()
read()

myDf = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(myDf)
```

input:

```
1023 David Shaw
red
189 165
1049 Amelia Serrano
yellow
145 124
```

output:

```
     Id FirstName LastName category  sWeight  eWeight
0  1023     David     Shaw      red      189      165
1  1049    Amelia  Serrano   yellow      145      124
```

Comment: As per the last changes you made, you can modify the code accordingly to rename the column names and set the index column.

Comment: How do you replace the two `read()` calls with something that reads a complete file with an arbitrary number of observations?  The example is only showing two observations but any real use case will have multiple observations.

Comment: There are multiple ways, either by running a for loop till (total_number_of_lines//no_of_lines_in_one_input). The other way would be making sure the end of file is not reached using seekg() in the read() function, and running a while loop unless a False value is returned from read() function (which would be returned if end of file occurs).